# Destination Location Code for anywhere in the world

Tags: amadeus

I'd like to know if there is a specific code to mention on the API on the required field destination location code in order to have all the destinations possible from my origin location code ? or a possibility to fill nothing in the destination location code ?
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you check out the [Flight Inspiration Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-inspiration-search) API which provides a list of destinations from a given origin.

You can also have a look at this [article](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/cheap-flights-to-anywhere-amadeus-flight-search) which explains how to build an anywhere search with the API.